# Script invisible in Chrome console before a refresh, works well with Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, page-refresh

I have to develop a short script, a quote generator for my course, and encounter a strange problem. The script works well with Firefox but need a page refresh to work correctly with Chrome.

I have already tried to include all my code in a function called with window.onload, but it changed nothing.
I have also tried to put the script tag at the end of the html file, and also nothing changed, still this problem.

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-compatible" content="IE-edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale-1">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

 <title>Citations pour héros et héroïnes</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

JS code:

```
// Tableaux de données
const firstSFArray = ["Je suis", "Je serais", "J'ai été"];
const secondSFArray = ["un pilote", "un aventurier", "un explorateur", "un 
agent", "un chercheur", "un colon"];
const thirdSFArray = ["de Vénus", "de Mars", "d'Alpha Centauri", "des tréfonds de la Galaxie", "du Néant"];

const firstFanArray = ["Je suis", "Je serais", "J'ai été"];
const secondFanArray = ["un marchand", "un guerrier", "un barbare", "un 
sorcier", "un élémentaire", "un voleur"];
const thirdFanArray = ["d'Hyrule", "de Cimmérie", "des Terres du Milieu", "de Poudlard", "du Pandémonium", "de l'Autre Monde"];

// Génération de la citation
let result;

function generator(array1, array2, array3) {
  const random1 = array1[Math.floor(Math.random() * array1.length)];
  const random2 = array2[Math.floor(Math.random() * array2.length)];
  const random3 = array3[Math.floor(Math.random() * array3.length)];

result = random1 + " " + random2 + " " + random3;
}

// Question à l'utilisateur

while (true) {
  const firstQuestion = prompt("Une nouvelle citation O/N ?").toLowerCase();

  if (firstQuestion === 'o') {
    const secondQuestion = parseFloat(prompt('Combien de citations souhaitez-vous (1 à 5) ?', "1"));

      if (secondQuestion <= 5) {
        const thirdQuestion = prompt("Univers Science-Fiction (S) ou Fantastique (F) ?").toLowerCase();

          if (thirdQuestion === 'science-fiction' || thirdQuestion === 's') {

              for (let x = 0; x < secondQuestion; x++) {
                generator(firstSFArray, secondSFArray, thirdSFArray);
                const quote = result;
                console.log(quote);
              }
          } else if (thirdQuestion === 'fantastique' || thirdQuestion === 'f') {

              for (let x = 0; x < secondQuestion; x++) {
                generator(firstFanArray, secondFanArray, thirdFanArray);
                const quote = result;
                console.log(quote);
              }
          }
      }
  } else if (firstQuestion === 'n') {
    break;
  }
}
```

Get the script to work with Chrome and learn from where comes this problem I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Your script seems to run just fine. Tested in the Chrome dev tools and it works. Tested without dev tools (exactly the examples you provided), and it works. Only thing my dev tools was bitching about was "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token", because there is a newline after `"un` (line 2), but I think that's because of StackOverflow's formatting?

Comment: Thanks. Yes it's Stack formating. 
The script worked directly when you opened the page with Chrome? You didn't need to reload it to see the different quotes?

Comment: Exactly. I saved your html as "test.html", your js as "script.js", loaded it, and it worked on the first load. Chrome 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Same version... Ok, really strange problem.
I have ghostery installed. Can he block such a script?

Comment: No clue! Try to run with it disabled? Maybe in incognito?

Comment: Then disabled that fcker for now ;).